BigQuery Error about SELECT list expression references column date which is neither grouped nor aggregated at []
Recently I have been learning SQL and when I tried the following code I got an error, I would like to know what's wrong with the code
SELECT
  CAST(date AS date) AS date_only,
  CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64),
  SUM(CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64)) AS total
FROM
  `lash09.customer_data.customer_purchase`
WHERE
  date BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31'

and the error I got is ,
SELECT list expression references column date which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:3]
I would like to know the correct code for calculating the sales of that particular month. And also I would like to know what went wrong with my code

You are using an aggregate function SUM without grouping the remaining select list columns . Meaning CAST(date AS date) AS date_only and CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64) should be added after the '2020-12-31' on a GROUP BY clause

You have not grouped by anything. You do this by adding the field name (and any conversions required in them) after the WHERE and before any ORDER BY.
The number of things you group by is the number of fields you are selecting MINUS any aggregated fields (sum, avg etc). So you are selecting 3 fields, but 1 is aggregated, so you need to specify 2 fields in the GROUP BY.
That said, some things to note:
You are CASTing a date field to datatype of date. This assumes that it is not already a datatype of date. You can’t use it “as is” in the WHERE clause until you change the datatype of the date field in the WHERE clause to a datatype of date. It has to match the treatment (if any, in this case CASTing) in the SELECT. I’ll assume it is not a date and leave the conversion.
If purchase_price is already a number/float then you don’t need to convert that either. I’ll assume for now it is not and leave the conversion.
The GROUP BY does not need to have the same treatment (eg. CAST()) explicitly specified. Using the field name is sufficient. Note you have to use the field name as specified in the table, not any alias you have give the field (unless the table’s field name and the alias are the same).
TIP: You can GROUP BY using the position number of each field from the SELECT as a number, so date is 1, purchase_price is 2 etc. This is especially useful when you have a complicated conversion or regex etc on a field you are selecting on.
Here’s your code after all the above is taken into account:
SELECT
  CAST(date as date) AS date_only,
  CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64)) as purchase_price,
SUM(CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64)) AS total
FROM
  `lash09.customer_data.customer_purchase`
WHERE
  CAST(date AS date) BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY date, purchase_price

Or using the positional number of the fields in the SELECT clause (I am not sure the official term for this):
SELECT
  CAST(date AS date) AS date_only,
  CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64)) as purchase_price,
  SUM(CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64)) AS total
FROM
  `lash09.customer_data.customer_purchase`
WHERE
  CAST(date AS date) BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY 1,2

